# How to modify a dataframe within a S4 object

Tags: r, dataframe, r-s4

I wanted to modify a dataframe (named "junction.counts") within a S4 object (named "gbcounts") and then use this "new" S4 object for subsequent analysis but don't know how to do that. Please refer to the below screenshot:

[screenshot of gbcounts which is a S4 object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfku1.png)

My goal is to remove all the unwanted rows in the "junction.counts" dataframe as they cause error in the next step. I was able to extract this dataframe using `JunctionCounts <- gbcounts@junction.counts` and then filtered out the unwanted features using `JunctionCounts2 = subset(JunctionCounts, gene_coordinates != "-")` but I need to put this modified dataframe back to the gbcount S4 object so that I can do subsequent analysis using this function in the ASpli package `asd <- jCounts(counts=gbcounts, features=features, minReadLength=100)`.

I've been reading several posts on how to modify S4 object but so far none is similar to my problem.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Put it back the same way you got it out, `gbcounts@junction.counts <- JunctionCounts2`

Comment: Oh IT WORKED!! I can't believe it's that simple. You save my day!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! I've spent two days on reading about modify S4 jobject and still can't understand it. I wish I should have posted my question much earlier.